# Fixing Json formatting issue in Groovy: Apache NiFi ExecuteScript

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I am working with [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/) and one of my flowfile is a slightly malformed Json:

```
{
"field" : "value",
"field1" : "value1"

}0;0
```

Instead of juggling with the transformation applied before, I would like to use a Groovy script as part of [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html). This is what I have at the moment:

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*


def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
    def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    def resultingText = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('}'))
    def json = slurper.parseText(resultingText)

    outputStream.write(json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

However, I am returned with the following error:

```
ExecuteScript[id=69ae1948-f20b-446c-b33f-298c6faa7c98] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char [SPACE] with an int value of 32

The current character read is [SPACE] with an int value of 32
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char [SPACE] with an int value of 32
line number 5
index number 61

...^: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char [SPACE] with an int value of 32

The current character read is [SPACE] with an int value of 32
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char [SPACE] with an int value of 32
line number 5
index number 61
```

...^

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?
 Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Write out the json without the `0;0`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do, after having used substring to only return everything before the '}', but I must have using it incorrectly, I guess

Comment: @tim_yates, thank you so much. Have a look at my posted answer. My issue is really that I do not have a valid Json format.

Comment: You ignored the second half of my answer...  You're serializing a map to a string which isn't what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end index of substring is not inclusive.  Therefore, you need:

```
def resultingText = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('}') + 1)
```

Or, you can use a range in groovy (which is inclusive)

```
def resultingText = text[0..text.indexOf('}')]
```

That is then your result.  No point parsing it into a map with `JsonSlurper` (unless you just want to validate that it is valid)...  And `json.toString()` will not be returning what you want it to, it will be returning a String representation of a Map

And this will break if any of your input json has nested objects :-(

```
def resultingText = text[0..text.lastIndexOf('}')]
```

Might fare better :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with this (thank you @tim_yates):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
    def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    def resultingText = text[0..text.lastIndexOf('}')]
    def json = slurper.parseText(resultingText)

   outputStream.write(json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

The posted example is only a part of the real Json. Unfortunately, the Json has many quirks such as having value with double quotes. For example:

```
{
 "field" : ""value""
}0;0
```

The above code works with the following format:

```
{
 "field" : "value"
}0;0
```

I think I need to format the Json and then I can have the removal of the extra characters working. Is there a simple way to ensure the format is correct?

Thank you so much

EDIT:

I was actually wrong, the returned value after running the script is:

```
{field=value}
```

EDIT. This is now working:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
    def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    def resultingText = text[0..text.lastIndexOf('}')].replaceAll('""', '"')

    outputStream.write(resultingText.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

However, there are still a number of quirks in the data that will be a burden later on in the dataflow. Here is an example of the full Json:

```
{"field1": "D",
 "field2": "12345",
 "field3": "myText",
 "field4": ,
 "field5": "B2",
 "field6": "B",
 "field7": 74664",
 "field8": 2,
 "field9": [something."2334", something."9973"],
 "field10": ,
 "field11": "9,
 "field12": "J"}
```

I have managed to remove the double '"', but I am concerned with the values that have either the right or left " (e.g. field7 and field11), values with no "" whatsoever (field8, for example), the null values and field9, which should really be `["something.2334", "something.9973"]`

I wonder how I can ensure that the Json is in a correct format (for later ingestion into a Db, for example).

Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my answer, you shouldn't be doing `json.toString()`...  `json` is a Map.  You already have valid json.  it's in `resultingText`

Comment: You are very much right @tim_yates, have a look at my reply and thank you so much for your help.